# Newbie Help regarding Struts2 and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I am new to struts2 and hibernate, I am trying to create an application in which i have a users table in which user has 
Id
firstname
lastname 
email
password

I want to create a login form on the basis of email and password can someone please guide me how to do that using hibernate 3 and struts 2

Thanks in advance
Anosh

Comment: Slightly related: please make sure you don't store plaintext passwords in the database.  http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple google search will help you to find the answer.Still here are the inputs.

Struts2 will responsible for getting the user-id and password from UI to action class and will pass this information to any service class which will with the help of hibernate will let you know if the user is valid or not.

a small demo example will be like

### JSP

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <s:form id="user_login" action="userLogin">
     <s:textfield name="userid" id="userid"/>
     <s:password name="password"/>
      <s:submit value="Login">
  </s:form>
</body>
```

Second step is to create an action class which will responsible to talk to hibernate to check if user exists or not

### Action

```
public class UserLoginAction extends ActionSupport{

  private String userid;
  private String password;

  getter and setter for above properties

  public String execute() throws Exception{
    // call you Service class to check if user is thee or not
       if (UserService.loginUser(userid,password)){
                return SUCCESS;
       }
       else{
            return INPUT;
       }

  }  

}
```

Finally we need to map them in struts.xml

### struts.xml

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="userLogin" class="com.demo.UserLoginAction">
        <result>/jsp/welcome.jsp</result>
                <result name="input">/jsp/login.jsp</result>
      </action>
</package>
```

How you will intact with hibernate is you have to create a `HibernateSession` and than need to fire a query using `Session` and based on that need to return result to Action class.
A small search about Hibernate will give you lots of results